# The related product import done only 100 product on every time in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I have tried to import bulk related-products for the respective product by using the CSV file. On every time import process, only 100 products are updated then stopped even showed import done message. I am using Magento 2.4.1 version. Please suggest to me how to update related products to all the products at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's a default function of magento. If you want import more than 100 products, you need custom module  import/export or use third party support it.